# Why jQuery selector is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this not working?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var content = '<a href="http://example.com/index.php><b>Some text!</b></a> - <a href="http://example.com/index.php" class="ot-origin-anchor">News</a>';

            $("#test").replaceWith(function(){

                return content;

            });
            //Here is the problem. I don't know why but I can't define adres.
            var adres = $("#test .ot-origin-anchor").attr("href");

            //find example.com - ugly :P
            var adresRegExp = adres.match(/(\w+:\/\/+(www.|))([^/]+)/);

            alert(RegExp.$3);

        });

    </script>

    <div id="test">bnb</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?,if you want to define a link into the div i think that's wrong

Comment: I'm trying change "News" into "example.com" (content is from Google Buzz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) call, there is no element on the page with ID `test`. It looks like you meant to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) or [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) instead of `.replaceWith()`.

```
var content = '<a href="http://example.com/index.php><b>Some text!</b></a> - <a href="http://example.com/index.php" class="ot-origin-anchor">News</a>';

$("#test").html(content);
// or
$("#test").append(content);

var adres = $("#test .ot-origin-anchor").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceWith` replaces every element in the selection to which it is applied. That would mean you'd end up with just `content` after the replace. So your next query, which looks for `#test` would match nothing. `#test` is gone. You replaced it with content.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing #test with your content variable so the selector isn't finding an element with id test.  Try  `$("#test").html(content);` instead.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sHGrB/

Comment: In your example is only "News", and should be "Some text! - News".

Comment: You were missing a quote in the first anchor tag. Update: http://jsfiddle.net/sHGrB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why use replace with? Use the jQuery `.html()` method to add it to the DOM, after that, you should be able to select it easily. **[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/5Ppns/)**.

Comment: I don't know why but when I try before .html() destroy my content, anyway thank you.

Comment: @Non `.replaceWith()` is **even more destructive** than `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace:

```
 $("#test").replaceWith(function(){

            return content;

        });
```

with:

```
$("#test").html(content);
```

You will get you the results you want, because #test no longer exists with replace

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here, one is that replaceWith is actually replacing `#test` with `content`. Then, your selector is looking for `#test .ot-origin-anchor` which doesn't exist, because `#test` was clobbered. Instead you should do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = '<a href="http://example.com/index.php><b>Some text!</b></a> - <a href="http://example.com/index.php" class="ot-origin-anchor">News</a>';

    $("#test").html(content);
    var address = $("#test .ot-origin-anchor").attr("href");
    var addressRegExp = address.match(/(\w+:\/\/+(www.|))([^/]+)/);

    alert(RegExp.$3);
});
```